# Dont want alertDailog Edittext to accept null values

Tags: android

this is my AlertDailog code..
most code in the positive button section is meant to be ignored and supposed to execute only when a non null value is inserted in edittext.

```
    private void Alert() {
        final EditText txt = new EditText(this);

         txt.setHint("Enter Survey Title");


AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder=new AlertDialog.Builder(CreateSurvey.this);
            alertBuilder
                    .setTitle("Set Title")
                    .setMessage("Name your Survey")
                    .setView(txt)
                    .setPositiveButton("Proceed", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                            if (txt.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter Title", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//TRIED RETURN ON IF 
                                return;
                            }
                            String text = txt.getText().toString().toUpperCase();
                            SurveyTitle.setText(text);

                            boolean bool;
                            bool = Mydb.insertData(text, 0, 0);
                            sno = Mydb.selectMaxId();
                            if (bool = true) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Survey Initiated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                                FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab2);
                                floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {

                                        try {
                                            Intent intent1 = new Intent(CreateSurvey.this, AddQuestions.class);
                                            intent1.putExtra("Sno", sno);
                                            startActivity(intent1);
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }

                                    }
                                });

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Survey Initiated failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }


                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
        ;
AlertDialog alertDialog=alertBuilder.create();
alertDialog.show();



    }
```

Tried return on if statement but it closes the alertDailog, but I want alertDailog to stay as long as some non null value is entered and clicked. I have seen solution using alertDailog.dismiss() but that doesn't work either.
Thank you!

Comment: You should remove all code that isn't related ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `dismiss()` if you declare the onclick listener after creating the dialog:

```
final EditText txt = new EditText(this);
AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

final AlertDialog dialog = alertBuilder // make this dialog final

        (...)

        .setPositiveButton("Proceed", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // leave empty
                }
            })

        (...)

        .create();

dialog.show();

dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (txt.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter Title", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                dialog.dismiss();
                // do your stuff here with valid title
            }
        }
    });
```